# Import data from FoxPor .dbc files, re-create .frx reports in Excel / Power BI

Tags: excel, visual-foxpro, foxpro, powerbi, powerquery

there's an app in our company running on Visual FoxPro.
I need to create MS Power BI reports based on data from this app.
Files can be exported from the app manually to excel, which takes some time.
Ideally there was a data connection to Power BI to refresh data.

Opened .dbc file in VFP9, lots of tables and connections.
No app documentation available, don't know where to start.
Imported some data into x32 Access and Excel with MS ODBC connector.
Don't know how to re-create the connections and business-logic.

Opened .frx files for business logic. how do I convert that in Excel?
I am initially an Excel user, don't know any SQL or FoxPro.
Could learn MS Access if there's a way to import data from FoxPro.

So, I am not looking for a tool to migrate data from FoxPro.
But to refresh FoxPro DB data and re-create .frx logic in Excel / Power BI.

Is this feasable?

Comment: FRX files are report definitions. Most of the time, they contain little, if any, logic. Mostly, they're the report layout with maybe some info about totalling and grouping. From the VFP side, there are tools that will convert a report (the result, not the FRX) to Excel format, but you'd need a way to hook that into your application.

Comment: From what you are saying, my suggestion is that you stay away from that app. If getting data into excel would work for you, then use OLEDB driver (VFPOLEDB) and Querytables.Add method. ODBC driver works for VFP6 and earlier formats (unless it is ADS driver).

Comment: You might get better answers if you explain what connections and business-logic you're trying to re-create in Power Query, and the errors you see.